# Simple ascii url encoding with python

Tags: python, urlencode, turbogears, turbogears2

look at that:

```
import urllib
print urllib.urlencode(dict(bla='Ã'))
```

the output is

```
bla=%C3%BC
```

what I want is simple, I want the output in ascii instead of utf-8, so I need the output:

```
bla=%C3
```

if I try:

```
urllib.urlencode(dict(bla='Ã'.decode('iso-8859-1')))
```

doesn't work (all my python files are utf-8 encoded):

`'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: ordinal not in range(128)`

In production, the input comes unicoded.

Comment: A+tilde converted to ASCII (?) is 0xC3 ? i don't think so

Comment: It might be worth rephrasing the title.  ASCII does not include an 'Ã' character.

Comment: "bla=%C3%BC" contains no non-ASCII characters. You need to explain what you really want/need and why you think that you need it.

Comment: @mykhal: U+00C3 is LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH TILDE. "\xC3" is mapped to U+00C3 in ISO-8859-1 and cp1252. What are you trying to say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to all solutions. all of you converge to the very same point.
I made a mess changing the right code

```
.encode('iso-8859-1')
```

to

```
.decode('iso-8859-1')
```

turn back to .encode('iso-8859-1') and it works.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [unicode transliteration in python](http://www.tablix.org/~avian/blog/archives/2009/01/unicode_transliteration_in_python/):

```
from unidecode import unidecode
print unidecode(u"\u5317\u4EB0")

# That prints: Bei Jing
```

In your case:

```
bla='Ã'
print unidecode(bla)
'A'
```

---

This is a third party library, which can be easily installed via:

```
$ git clone http://code.zemanta.com/tsolc/git/unidecode
$ cd unidecode
$ python setup.py install
```

Answer (score 2):

> I want the output in ascii instead of utf-8

That's not ASCII, which has no characters mapped above 0x80. You're talking about ISO-8859-1, or possibly code page 1252 (the Windows encoding based on it).

```
'Ã'.decode('iso-8859-1')
```

Well that depends on what encoding you've used to save the character `Ã` in the source, doesn't it? It sounds like your text editor has saved it as UTF-8. (That's a good thing, because locale-specific encodings like ISO-8859-1 need to go away ASAP.)

Tell Python that the source file you've saved is in UTF-8 as per [PEP 263](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/):

```
# coding=utf-8

urllib.quote(u'Ã'.encode('iso-8859-1'))    # -> %C3
```

Or, if you don't want that hassle, use a backslash escape:

```
urllib.quote(u'\u00C3'.encode('iso-8859-1'))    # -> %C3
```

Although, either way, a modern webapp should be using UTF-8 for its input rather than ISO-8859-1/cp1252.

Comment: the entire webapp is already utf-8, but the external url-based webservice that I am trying to communicate doesn't recognize %C3%BC, only %C3. your solution works fine.

Answer (score 2):

pretty well working asciification is this way:

```
import unicodedata
unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', 'Ã'.decode('UTF-8')).encode('ascii', 'ignore')
```

Answer (score 1):

If your input is actually UTF-8 and you want iso-8859-1 as output (which is not ASCII) what you need is:

```
'ñ'.decode('utf-8').encode('iso-8859-1')
```

Answer (score 0):

Package [`unihandecode`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unihandecode) is

> US-ASCII transliterations of Unicode text.
>   an improved version of Python unidecode, that is Python port of Text::Unidecode Perl module by Sean M. Burke .

```
pip install Unihandecode
```

then in `python`

```
import unihandecode
print(unihandecode.unidecode(u'Ã'))
```

prints `A`.