# Replace special characters with ASCII equivalent

Tags: python, unicode

Is there any lib that can replace special characters to ASCII equivalents, like:

```
"Cześć"
```

to:

```
"Czesc"
```

I can of course create map:

```
{'ś':'s', 'ć': 'c'}
```

and use some replace function. But I don't want to hardcode all equivalents into my program, if there is some function that already does that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple ascii url encoding with python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114176/simple-ascii-url-encoding-with-python)

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382998/latin-1-to-ascii

Comment: look for `Unihandecode`

Answer (score 50, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import unicodedata
text = u'Cześć'
print unicodedata.normalize('NFD', text).encode('ascii', 'ignore')
```

Comment: 'NFKD' would give you ASCII output more often than 'NFD' would.

Comment: it doesnt work for all cases i.e. `(VW Polo) - Zapłon Jak sprawdzić czy działa pompa wspomagania?`
converts to
`(VW Polo)  - Zapon jak sprawdzic czy dziaa pompa wspomagania?`

Answer (score 24):

The package [unidecode](https://pypi.org/project/Unidecode/) worked best for me:

```
from unidecode import unidecode
text = "Björn, Łukasz and Σωκράτης."
print(unidecode(text))
# ==> Bjorn, Lukasz and Sokrates.
```

You might need to install the package:

```
pip install unidecode
```

---

The above solution is easier and more robust than encoding (and decoding) the output of `unicodedata.normalize()`, as suggested by other answers.

```
# This doesn't work as expected:
ret = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', text).encode('ascii', 'ignore')
print(ret)
# ==> b'Bjorn, ukasz and .'
# Besides not supporting all characters, the returned value is a
# bytes object in python3. To yield a str type:
ret = ret.decode("utf8") # (not required in python2)
```

Comment: It translates "ß" into "ss", but "ä" into "a", not "ae".

Comment: @RobinDinse This is intentional, see the docu of [unidecode](https://pypi.org/project/Unidecode/) for the reasoning behind this. You can always replace the three umlauts äöü yourself prior to passing a string to unidecode.

Answer (score 23):

You can get most of the way by doing:

```
import unicodedata

def strip_accents(text):
    return ''.join(c for c in unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', text) if unicodedata.category(c) != 'Mn')
```

Unfortunately, there exist accented Latin letters that cannot be decomposed into an ASCII letter + combining marks.  You'll have to handle them manually.  These include:

- Æ → AE
- Ð → D
- Ø → O
- Þ → TH
- ß → ss
- æ → ae
- ð → d
- ø → o
- þ → th
- Œ → OE
- œ → oe
- ƒ → f

Answer (score 5):

Try the [trans](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/trans) package. Looks very promising. Supports Polish.

Comment: This was perfect for me, and it's BSD-licensed.

Comment: For me too, works like charm

Answer (score 4):

I did it this way:

```
POLISH_CHARACTERS = {
    50309:'a',50311:'c',50329:'e',50562:'l',50564:'n',50099:'o',50587:'s',50618:'z',50620:'z',
    50308:'A',50310:'C',50328:'E',50561:'L',50563:'N',50067:'O',50586:'S',50617:'Z',50619:'Z',}

def encodePL(text):
    nrmtxt = unicodedata.normalize('NFC',text)
    i = 0
    ret_str = []
    while i < len(nrmtxt):
        if ord(text[i])>128: # non ASCII character
            fbyte = ord(text[i])
            sbyte = ord(text[i+1])
            lkey = (fbyte << 8) + sbyte
            ret_str.append(POLISH_CHARACTERS.get(lkey))
            i = i+1
        else: # pure ASCII character
            ret_str.append(text[i])
        i = i+1
    return ''.join(ret_str)
```

when executed:

```
encodePL(u'ąćęłńóśźż ĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŹŻ')
```

it will produce output like this:

```
u'acelnoszz ACELNOSZZ'
```

This works fine for me - ;D

Answer (score 1):

The unicodedata.normalize gimmick can best be described as half-assci. Here is a [robust approach](http://effbot.org/zone/unicode-convert.htm) which includes a map for letters with no decomposition. Note the additional map entries in the comments.