# downgrade non-ascii symbols to closest 7-bit ASCII equivalent (preferrably Java)

Tags: java, unicode, character-encoding, ascii

is there any simple/lightweight solution to change at least some of non-ASCII symbols to respective ASCII analogs? For example this string

```
abc-åäö.txt
```

should be changed to

```
abc-aao.txt
```

A bit of background: Zip-tools do not reliably support UTF-8, hence the need to downgrade. AFAICR Google "download attachments as single zip file" feature replaces any non-ascii symbols with the '_' character.

PS: the code might as well be in some other language, if it's more or less understandable I'll port that to Java.
PPS: my first question so far, so please don't minus me below the ground okay?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting Symbols, Accent Letters to English Alphabet.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008802/converting-symbols-accent-letters-to-english-alphabet)

Comment: So how would we proceed, close this as a duplicate? Questions apparently are quite close but I still was unable to see that one before posting mine...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replace national characters with ASCII equivalent.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3194516/replace-national-characters-with-ascii-equivalent)

Comment: look for `Unihandecode`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at `java.text.Normalizer`. It can help you with transforming equivalent characters: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this](http://www.alphaworks.ibm.com/tech/unicodenormalizer) would do?

Comment: thanks for the reference, but I don't see the actual code there, apparently this is either already a part of JRE (that java.text.Normalizer or something similar) or not a lightweight solution...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the problem is solved here -

[solution][howto] Convert special characters to normal chars (Ã© to e) 
http://www.ramonfincken.com/permalink/topic192.html

Answer (score 1):

If you would consider using python, there is a pretty good python package called [unidecode](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode), which can get the ASCII transliterations of Unicode text.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, found something more or less working in this question:
[PHP: Replace umlauts with closest 7-bit ASCII aequivalent in an UTF-8 string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158241/php-replace-umlauts-with-closest-7-bit-ascii-aequivalent-in-an-utf-8-string)