# How to edit data received through forms in django?

Tags: django, forms, unicode, utf-8, request

I'm learning Django. There is a search bar. That is intended to be used with russian words. 
The word is caught with a simple form.

How can I encode the word to utf-8 right at the beginning ? It creates the UnicodeEncodeError at some point because of this.
Or what are the ways to change the original request?

The database is set to utf-8.

Thank you.

Here is the Traceback

```
Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/teodor/moldova/search/views.py" in results
  27.   return render_to_response(template_name, locals(), context_instance = RequestContext(request))

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/shortcuts/__init__.py" in render_to_response
  20.     return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs), **httpresponse_kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  176.         return t.render(context_instance)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  140.             return self._render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  823.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  74.             return node.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  123.         return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  823.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  74.             return node.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  123.         return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  823.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  74.             return node.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  62.             result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  823.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  74.             return node.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  62.             result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  823.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  74.             return node.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  1178.                     _dict = func(*resolved_args, **resolved_kwargs)

File "/home/teodor/moldova/search/templatetags/search_tags.py" in pagination_links
  23.   params = urllib.urlencode(raw_params)

File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib.py" in urlencode
  1267.             v = quote_plus(str(v))

Exception Type: UnicodeEncodeError at /search/results/
Exception Value: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I did a search for word: Найти

Comment: You shouldn't need to encode at all: stay in Unicode as much as possible. Post the actual traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t have much experience with this, but as per [Jonathan “Wolf” Rentzsch’s guide to using UTF-8 on the web](http://rentzsch.tumblr.com/post/9133498042/howto-use-utf-8-throughout-your-web-stack), you might want to try adding the `accept-charset="UTF-8"` attribute to your `<form>` tag.

Where are you seeing the `UnicodeEncodeError`? Can you show us some code?

**Edit:** ah, okay. Yup — I *think* Django provides all text as Unicode objects. If I’m understanding the traceback correctly, the issue occurs when you call `str` on this unicode object to use it with `urllib.quote_plus`.

I *think* you need to provide `urllib.quote_plus` with text encoded in ASCII (See e.g. [Is there a unicode-ready substitute I can use for urllib.quote and urllib.unquote in Python 2.6.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5557849/is-there-a-unicode-ready-substitute-i-can-use-for-urllib-quote-and-urllib-unquot)).

And as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114176/simple-ascii-url-encoding-with-python), I think you can do that like this:

```
import unicodedata
v_as_ascii = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', v.decode('UTF-8')).encode('ascii', 'ignore')
v = quote_plus( v_as_ascii )
```

(I haven’t tested any of this though, so I could be entirely wrong. Hopefully someone who has experience with this stuff will come by.)